# Is it possible to have a singleton exist accross different projects within a solution?

Tags: c#, singleton

I am attempting to communicate information between two different projects. One is a remoting server and the other a WPF application. I have created a singleton class but have noticed that each time one project calls the GetInstance method it creates a new instance of the singleton. Is it possible to have a singleton accross projects as it doesn't seem it is and if that is the case, why is that?
Below is my code for the singleton

```
public class CommunicationSingleton
{
    private int jobCount = 0;
    private Job jobInProgress;
    private List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();
    private static CommunicationSingleton instance = new CommunicationSingleton();
    static readonly object obj = new object();

    private CommunicationSingleton() { }

    public static CommunicationSingleton GetInstance()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                return instance = new CommunicationSingleton();
            }
            else
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddJob(Job job)
    {
        jobs.Add(job);
    }

    public List<Job> GetJobs()
    {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void IncreaseJobCount(int jobCount)
    {
        this.jobCount += jobCount;
    }

    public int GetJobCount()
    {
        return jobCount;
    }

    public void JobInProgress(Job jobInProgress)
    {
        this.jobInProgress = jobInProgress;
    }

    public Job GetJobInProgress()
    {
        return jobInProgress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Singleton is the wrong concept. You are not concerned with a program/process having only exactly one instance of something, you are concerned about two or more processes exchanging data with each other, as i understand it. If my understanidng is correcy, you might want to look into and learn about pipes.

Comment: My apologies, i fat-fingered my previous comment. It is not "pipelines", it is "pipes" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipe-operations)